# php pagination without database

Tags: php

How to create pagination script with out database support,

i have 200 images in my images folder,

i want to display these images with pagination ,

if DB means we use some count to we can create pagination , but its clearly mentioned no database, so how to create the pagination ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put all files into an array
2. [Slice the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) according to page number and number of pictures.

Exapmle code:

```
$images = glob('img/*.jpg');

$img_count = count($images);
$per_page = 10;

$max_pages = ceil($img_count / $per_page);

$show = array_slice($images, $per_page * intval($_GET['page']) - 1, $per_page);

if($_GET['page'] > 1)
    $prev_link = '<a href="images.php?page='.($_GET['page']-1).'"> previous </a>';
if($_GET['page'] < $max_pages)
    $next_link = '<a href="images.php?page='.($_GET['page']+1).'"> next </a>';
```

Comment: what is the logic should i use, to display next and back link, so far i used just pager class for my paginations

Comment: I've edited the code to show the logic. Just check if current page is first or last, and increase or decrease page number in your links.

Comment: but query string going negative  and also next link missing in some situtaion

Comment: @Bharanikumar Write a condition to prevent this. Are you a programmer or what?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, what I did to make it work correctly is adjusting this line: `$show = array_slice($images, $per_page * intval($_GET['page']) - 1, $per_page);` into `$show = array_slice($images, $per_page * intval($_GET['page']) - $per_page, $per_page);` Because when I had `$per_page = 10;` It would slice from 9 till 10.. Because 10 * 1 - 1 = 9... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to read the directory, they your count is the length of the array returned by `glob()`.

The rest would be the same as when you would use a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all of the image names in the directory into an array, maybe using `opendir`. Then use this array as your database.