# Show next/previous post title without link in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the links to next and previous webpages from my directory. I searched on the web and found this

```
<?php 
$prev_post = get_adjacent_post('', '', true);
$next_post = get_adjacent_post('', '', false);
?>
<p><?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></p>
```

This is what I want to do, let's say I have three posts. sitename.com/current.php , sitename.com/previous.php , sitename.com/next.php If I am on current.php I want to show links of previous.php and next.php How can I do that?

Comment: You would Google "php pagination". Are you wanting to use a database or not?

Comment: I want to show a complete post and then at the bottom of post the links to next and previous posts. How could I use pagination for this?

Comment: Google >>> pagination without database php - You can even find something using JS.

Comment: Do I need pagination even for showing one link?

Comment: I don't know, do you? You asked how to do pagination which that is what that piece of code does, so I answered. I also asked if you were wanting to do this with a DB or not; do you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3857110/ base yourself on that.

Comment: Thank you. I think that will work If I set number of results per page to just one.

Comment: As per your edit: Google >>> "if current page php" - One result found http://stackoverflow.com/q/15717516/ see that Q&A's. Then http://stackoverflow.com/q/13032930/ and https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/php-if-url-is-homepage-then-do-this.499517/ those should get you started.